# How to concatenate multiple rows in one column with derby database

Tags: java, sql, concatenation, derby

```
SELECT DISTINCT sec.fileEntry_id,
                sec.scene_id,
                sec.name,
                sec.KholaseSecance,
                sec.honarvar,
                sec.mavaredKhas,
                sec.numberKhatSecance,
                (CASE
                     WHEN cod.name = 'خارجی' THEN secObj.text
                     ELSE NULL
                 END) AS "khareji",
                (CASE
                     WHEN cod.name = 'داخلی' THEN secObj.text
                     ELSE NULL
                 END) "dakhali",
                (CASE
                     WHEN cod.name = 'روز' THEN secObj.text
                     ELSE NULL
                 END) "roz",
                (CASE
                     WHEN cod.name = 'شب' THEN secObj.text
                     ELSE NULL
                 END) "shab",
                (CASE
                     WHEN cod.name = 'بازیگراصلی' THEN secObj.text
                     ELSE NULL
                 END) "bazigarasli",
                (CASE
                     WHEN cod.name = 'بازیگرفرعی' THEN secObj.text
                     ELSE NULL
                 END) "bazigarfarie",
                (CASE
                     WHEN cod.name = 'لوکیشن اصلی' THEN secObj.text
                     ELSE NULL
                 END) "locationasli",
                (CASE
                     WHEN cod.name = 'لوکیشن فرعی' THEN secObj.text
                     ELSE NULL
                 END) "locationfarie",
                (CASE
                     WHEN cod.name = 'وسایل نقلیه' THEN secObj.text
                     ELSE NULL
                 END) "vasaielnaglie",
                (CASE
                     WHEN cod.name = 'وسایل صحنه' THEN secObj.text
                     ELSE NULL
                 END) "vasaielsahne"
FROM CODDING cod
INNER JOIN SCENEOBJECT secObj ON cod.codding_id=secObj.codding_id
INNER JOIN SCENE sec ON sec.scene_id=secObj.scene_id
WHERE sec.fileEntry_id=1
ORDER BY sec.scene_id ASC;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What you want to do is unclear.

Comment: I don't know Apache Derby. But in other databases all you need to do is add a `GROUP BY` for those `sec` fields. And then aggregate those `CASE WHEN` with a MAX.  F.e. `MAX(CASE WHEN cod.name = 'شب' THEN secObj.text END) AS "shab"`. (you won't need the `ELSE NULL`)(the DISTINCT is overhead when you have a GROUP BY)